# Download pdf on contact form 7 submit in new tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

i have created a from on contact form 7 and on submit have to download pdf.

They script works for me though. But however it oes not open in new tab. How to open new tab in window.location or if window.open how could i parse the value in urs.

```
function add_this_script_footer() { ?>
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( '170' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        var inputs = event.detail.inputs;
        var urs = inputs[6].value;
        window.location.href=urs;
        setTimeout(function(){ loation.reload(); }, 3000);
   }
   }, false );
   </script>
  <?php 
 } 

 add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `window.open` with target `_blank` like below.

```
 window.open(
      urs,
      '_blank' 
    );
```

Comment: it will be blocked by browsers